# jQuery slide / hide inconsistency

Tags: jquery

I have two radio buttons, to which I have assigned change handlers to show/hide certain divs based on the selection:

```
$("input[name='pick_up_point']").change(function()
{
    if($("input[name='pick_up_point']:checked").val() == "pick_up_airport")
    {
        $("#pick_up_airport_div").slideDown();
        $("#pick_up_attraction_div").hide();
    }
    else if($("input[name='pick_up_point']:checked").val() == "pick_up_attraction")
    {
        $("#pick_up_attraction_div").slideDown();
        $("#pick_up_airport_div").hide();
    }
});
```

This works fine, except for when I change the options in quick succession (mouse clicks or arrow keys), the div that is meant to hide is still displayed. If I change `slideDown()` to `show()` the issue does not occur.

This issue occurs in both Internet Explorer 8 and Firefox, is it a known bug (jQuery 1.4.2) or am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you need [`.stop(true, true)`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) (not just [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)), so the sliding animations don't stop mid-way, like this:

```
$("input[name='pick_up_point']").change(function()
{
    if($("input[name='pick_up_point']:checked").val() == "pick_up_airport")
    {
        $("#pick_up_airport_div").stop(true, true).slideDown();
        $("#pick_up_attraction_div").stop(true, true).hide();
    }
    else if($("input[name='pick_up_point']:checked").val() == "pick_up_attraction")
    {
        $("#pick_up_attraction_div").stop(true, true).slideDown();
        $("#pick_up_airport_div").stop(true, true).hide();
    }
});
```

With *just* [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/), it'll halt the animation, resulting in an element being *partially* slid down, and future slide-downs will only go to that height as well.  The second argument of [`.stop(bool, bool)`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) tells it whether to jump to the end, restoring the full height of the element, which is what you need in a [`.slideUp()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/) or [`.slideDown()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) situation (among others!).

Comment: Cheers, that has worked fine. Just another slight issue (this also occured before I added the stop() code in) - in IE8 sometimes the div's don't always appear in their correct position, i.e. they are slightly higher up than they should be. Usually clicking on the element somewhere will cause it to jump down to it's proper position.

Comment: Update on the above - from my testing it seems the issue only occurs when clicking on the LABEL rather than the radio button. There are no jQuery events attached to the label.

Comment: @GSTAR - A click on the label will trigger a `change` on the control it's for in this case...give `<div>` elements a width to fix the slide-down jumpyness...yes, width not height, just trust me :)

Answer (score 0):

Like mike said you would just add the .stop() function but you could still use your old code

```
$("#pick_up_airport_div").stop().slideDown();
```

What your describing is not a bug, it is the animation que building up. By pressing the input in quick succession it adds that animation to the que and fires it when its turn comes up. So using the [stop](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)
function it stops the what ever animation is going on. So by doing that you can prevent the buildup. Hope that helps.